# Reading text file with reaping pattern c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to read from a text file a hex number, using the last digit to define my length to read a string, again a number and so on until the line will finish.

```
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName)){
                String line = sr.ReadLine();
                string hexText = line.Substring(0,9);

                char c = hexText[8];
                int con = c - '0'; //saving the value
                string myHex = con.ToString("X");  
                int length = Convert.ToInt32(myHex, 16);
                string fieldChars = line.Substring(0, length); //getting the key
                string b = line.Substring(c, length); }
```

so for "5A3F00004olga" the length is correct and 4 (the last hex bit) but for some reason b is not Olga.Why?

Comment: Hi Monika. Your question indicates that you have a bug (error) in your code. StakOverflow isn't aimed at getting help with finding bugs. I recommend you learn about debugging by googling "debugging c# code", for example. If you are using Visual Studio, this video may help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-HdLtqEOog

Comment: What you need is a debugging on the code to find out what really happening there, So it's better to ask your question in a somehow different way or try to debug your code.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman What do you mean that Stackoverflow isn't aimed at getting help with finding bugs? Sure, we do encourage people to learn to use their debuggers and show them other ways to help find bugs, but we absolutely do help people find bugs in their code, and show them how to fix those bugs.

Comment: @JimMischel You're right, I worded my comment poorly. SO does help people find bugs, but that comes as a result of a carefully framed question that corresponds to an area of their own knowledge which they have identified to be lacking. SO questions should be more "When I do X, I expect Y, but I get Z, why?" and less "this code I wrote doesn't work, why?" -- because the answer to the latter is "debug your code". The former question style has a decent chance of being useful to someone else in future. The latter will almost never be useful to anyone else, ever. This question is the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a closer look at your code. You have:

```
char c = hexText[8];
int con = c - '0'; //saving the value
string myHex = con.ToString("X");  
int length = Convert.ToInt32(myHex, 16);
string fieldChars = line.Substring(0, length); //getting the key
string b = line.Substring(c, length);
```

So `c` contains the value of the character at position 8. I don't have any idea why you're subtracting '0' from it, and then converting the result back to a string. You could just as easily write:

```
string myHex = c + "X";
```

Also, if the value at `hexText[8]` were `'A'`, then subtracting '0' would give you 17 rather than the 10 that you expected.

I also don't know what you expect the line that assigns `fieldChars` to do, but I can pretty much guarantee that it's not doing what you want.

The reason `b` doesn't contain "olga" is because the substring starting position in this case would be `4` (44 in decimal), and `length` could be totally wrong as described above.

I think the code you want is:

```
char c = hexText[8];
string myHex = con.ToString("X");
int length = Convert.ToInt32(myHex, 16);
string b = line.Substring(9, length);
```

I didn't include `fieldChars` there because it's unclear to me what you want value you want that variable to hold. If you want the key, then you'd want `line.Substring(0, 8);` If you want the entire field, including the key, the length, and the text, you'd write `line.Substring(0, 9 + length);`

As suggested in comments, you can use the C# debugger to walk through your code one line at a time, and inspect variables to see what is happening. That's an excellent way to see the results of the code you write. Better yet is to work a few examples by hand before you start writing code. That way you get a better understanding of what the code is supposed to do. It makes writing correct code a whole lot easier.

If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn.

Another way you can see what's happening is to put `Console.WriteLine` statements after each line. For example:

```
char c = hexText[8];
Console.WriteLine("c = " + c);
```

If you do that after each line, or after each important group of lines, displaying the values of important variables, you can see exactly where your program is going off into the weeds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I asked after I used the debugger and didn't get the necessary values.

Comment: @Monika The point I was making is that `'A' - '0'` will not return 10. It will return 17.